# Gaussian plus some other distribution equals

Tags: normal-distribution

let say target  t

$$t = y(x,w) + e , e \ \sim \ N(e|0,\beta^{-1}) $$

in this case e is Gaussian normal distribution and

is whatever y(x,w) is t will be a normal distribution?

Comment: Would you see a use for `\sim` as in $\sim N(e\vert0,\beta^{-1})$? I'm not sure that's what you want to say, just trying to help you...

Comment: yes, sorry new to mathjax

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $x$ and $w$ aren't random variables themselves, then yes. The random variable $t$ will be distributed just like $e$, but with its mean shifted by $y(x, w)$.

Edit: on the other hand, if one of $x$ or $w$ is a random variable, $t$ could have a variety of different distributions depending on the distribution of $x$ or $w$. It could be normal, but it need not be.

Comment: It looks to me like the title makes it clear that x and w are not held constant; $t|x,w$ would be normal but I think the question is probably after the marginal rather than the conditional